using for loops to swap digits
using a for loop i have to write code to swap the 2nd and 3rd digit of a number given via user input in javascript.
for ( i = 0; i < entNum.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) num2 = entNum[i];
    else if (i === entNum.length - 2) {
        newNum = newNum + num2;
        newNum = entNum[i] + newNum;
    }
    else newNum = newNum + entNum[i];
}
console.log("New number:" + newNum)

this is the code i was able to produce however this code swaps the 1st and 2nd digit in the number and i can't seems to alter the code in the way to target the 2nd and 3rd digit nor do i 100% understand for loops and if statements. so a detailed explanation would be useful.

do you have some examples? what is entNum?

Why must you use a loop if you are specifically swapping the 2nd and 3rd digits?

e.g. lets say entNum = 345 @NinaScholz

its just part of the question i need to answer, @mykaf

You should always declare variables as local with let.

they are i just didn't include the that part of my code

Is entNum a string or a number? Are you counting digits from the left or right?

entNum is a string and it loops starting from the left i think

Loop over the input string, concatenating each digit to the output string. Except if the index is 1 or 2, append the digit at the other index to swap them.


let entNum = '123456';
let newNum = '';
for (let i = 0; i < entNum.length; i++) {
  let digit;
  if (i === 1) {
    digit = entNum[2];
  } else if (i == 2) {
    digit = entNum[1];
  } else {
    digit = entNum[i];
  }
  newNum += digit;
}
console.log("New number:" + newNum)




Omg, thank you!! This makes much more sense to me and easy to understand.

Usually you want to create functions for the things you make so you can reuse it. Here I'm converting your number into a string and then split it into an array, swap the digits and join back.


function swap(val, x, y) {
    let arr = (val + "").split("");
    let tmp = arr[x];
    arr[x] = arr[y];
    arr[y] = tmp;
    return parseInt(arr.join(""));
}

console.log(swap(12345, 1, 2));



If you really need a loop, then


function swaps(input, x, y) {
    let arr = (input + "").split("");
    for (let index = 0; index < x.length; index++) {
        let tmp = arr[x[index]];
        arr[x[index]] = arr[y[index]];
        arr[y[index]] = tmp;
    }
    return parseInt(arr.join(""));
}

console.log(swaps(123456, [1], [2]));




The assignment requires them to use a loop.

appreciate the answer but specifically was asking about for loops :)

@tamika edited my answer accordingly

yh..... this makes even less sense to me :(

Function to swap two consecutive values from starting position in a string using a loop:


const nr = `1234567`;
for (let i = 0; i < nr.length; i += 1) {
  console.log(`@ ${i} => ${swapNumbers(nr, i)}`);
}

console.log(`@ ${10} (just returns the string) => ${swapNumbers(nr, 10)}`);

function swapNumbers(str, atPos){
  const nrs = str.split(``);
  
  if (atPos >= nrs.length) { return str; }
  
  for (let i=0; i< nrs.length; i+=1) {
    if (i === atPos) {
      [nrs[i], nrs[i+1]] = [nrs[i+1], nrs[i]];
      break;
    }
  }
  return nrs.join(``)
}
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}



